# Can't see the window that comes up after clicking on a Button

Tags: selenium

I'm trying to automate the process of collecting 20 free coins on https://agar.io website every hour through Selenium. I login through facebook.

Here's my problem: After I click on the Free Coins button, a short pop up kind of window appears. I'm unable to locate any buttons on that pop up. Please help me understand the structure of their design and possibly, a solution!

I've attached a screenshot of the page below. Please help.

Thank You

[This is where I'm facing the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9znFy.png)

PS: I've used actions.moveToElement("*Free Coins button's id here"*).click().perform() to click on the Free Coins Button on the main page. It works sometimes and sometimes doesn't. Not sure why..

Comment: This stack overflow post may be of help to you http://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/8536

Comment: what type of element is the button in? is there an iframe perhaps? (if so, you need to tell your webdriver to switch to the iframe (` driver.switchTo().frame(...)`) is if flash? (if so, you can use `Actions` to click on certain coordinates, as suggested by HelpMePlz).

Comment: @SirLenz0rlot, Thanks for your reply. I'm very new to this. I don't completely understand what a flash is. Please click on the website link I posted so you can see what's happening.

Comment: I can not access the link from my location. with `flash`, I mean a Flashplayer thingy